# Drupal 6 Multistep Forms: form_state values empty on submit

Tags: php, forms, drupal

I'm having trouble getting the values from a multistep form to insert into the database. All I'm getting is empty values for each field.

Here's the code:

```
  function multistep_profile_menu() {
  $items['multistep_profile'] = array(
 'title' => t('Multistep Profile'),
 'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
 'page arguments' => array('multistep_profile'),
 'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
 'access arguments' => array('access content'),
 );
 return $items;
 }



 function multistep_profile(&$form_state) {
 // $form_state['storage']['step'] keeps track of what page we're on.
 if (!isset($form_state['storage']['step'])) {
 $form_state['storage']['step'] = 1;
 }

 //stores form data and carries it between steps
 $default_value = '';
 if (isset($form_state['storage']['values'][$form_state['storage']['step']])) {
  $default_value = $form_state['storage']['values'][$form_state['storage']['step']];
 }

 switch ($form_state['storage']['step']) {
 // Step 1 of Form
 case 1:
  $form['step_one'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Step 1'),
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#description' => t('Just getting started.'),

  );
  // Full Name
  $form['step_one']['full_name'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Full Name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#description' => t('Please enter your name.'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => isset($default_value['full_name']) ? $default_value['full_name'] :       '',

  );

  // College/University/Organization
  $form['step_one']['college'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('College/University/Organization'),
    '#default_value' => isset($default_value['college']) ? $default_value['college'] : '',
  );

  // Academic Disciplines
  $form['step_one']['academic'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Academic Disciplines'),
    '#default_value' => isset($default_value['academic']) ? $default_value['academic'] : '',
    );
  break;

// Step 2 of Form
case 2:
  $form['step_two'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Step 2'),
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#description' => t('Almost done.'),
  );

  // Job Title
  $form['step_two']['job_title'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Job Title'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#description' => t('Please enter your job title.'),
    '#default_value' => isset($default_value['job_title']) ? $default_value['job_title'] : '',
  );

  // Department
  $form['step_two']['department'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Department'),
    '#default_value' => isset($default_value['department']) ? $default_value['department'] : '',
  );
  break;
// Step 3 of Form  
case 3:
  $form['step_three'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Step 3'),
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#description' => t('Almost done, part 3.')
  );
  // Q1
  $form['step_three']['q1'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Why do you want to develop a globally networked course?'),
    '#type' => 'textarea',
    '#description' => t(''),

  );
  break;
//Confirmation  
case 4:
  $form['thanks'] = array(
    '#value' => '<p>'. t('Your Profile is complete.') .'</p>',
  );
  break;
  }

  //programmatically display buttons
 if ($form_state['storage']['step'] > 1) {
  $form['previous'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('<< Previous'),
  );
 }
 if ($form_state['storage']['step'] != 4) {
 $form['next'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Continue >>'),
 );
 }
 else {
 $form['finish'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => t('Finish'),
 );
 }
  return $form;
  }


 function multistep_profile_submit($form, &$form_state) {
 //Save the values for the current step into the storage array.
 $form_state['storage']['values'][$form_state['storage']['step']] = $form_state['values'];

 //Check the button that was clicked and change the step.
 if ($form_state['clicked_button']['#id'] == 'edit-previous') {
 $form_state['storage']['step']--;
  }
 elseif ($form_state['clicked_button']['#id'] == 'edit-next') {
 $form_state['storage']['step']++;
  }
 elseif ($form_state['clicked_button']['#id'] == 'edit-finish') {
//You should store the values from the form in the database here.


 dpm($form_state);
 // INSERT into DB

 $full_name = $form_state['values']['full_name'];
 $college = $form_state['values']['college']; 
 $academic = $form_state['values']['academic']; 
 $job_title = $form_state['values']['job_title'];
 $department = $form_state['values']['department'];
 $q1 = $form_state['values']['q1'];

 db_query("INSERT INTO {multistep_profile} (full_name, college, academic, job_title,    department, q1, created) VALUES
    ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', %d)", $full_name, $college, $academic, $job_title, $department, $q1, time());
  drupal_set_message(t('Your profile has been saved.'));


unset($form_state['storage']);

//Go to this page after completing the form.
//$form_state['redirect'] = 'node';
 }
 }
```

The only value that makes it into the DB is the 'created' date timestamp.

I ran a DPM to check if the values are being carried over between form steps, and they are, I just can't figure out how to get them to insert into the database. Any help?

Comment: just a guess but aren't the values meant to be in $form_state['values']['step_two']['job_title'] instead of $form_state['values']['job_title'] ?

Comment: That would theoretically work, but you would then have to add '#tree' => TRUE to each fieldset definition, i.e., in the $form['step_one'] array, and so on. I actually tried that last night, and it worked in terms of grouping the arrays when I look at the array structure with the DPM, but still didn't put the values in the DB.

Comment: This may be helpful, this is how the DPM gets printed, so you can see the array structure: http://postimage.org/image/j2s4774uz/

Comment: interesting issue. if you can't solve it by tonight, I have a look and get back to you. please update this issue if you got a solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your submit function, you (correctly) store the values collected on the different steps under `$form_state['storage']['values'][<step_number>]`. This matches with the DPM output you posted, i.e. the values show up under `$form_state['storage']['values'][1]...`, `$form_state['storage']['values'][2]...`, etc.

But in your final submit processing, you try to access them under `$form_state['values'][...]`, just as if this was a single step form. As your last step does not post any values, you will not find anything there.

So looks like you'd just need to change your final value collection logic to grab the values from the storage (sub)arrays where you have placed them before :)

E.g.:

```
$full_name = $form_state['values']['full_name'];
```

would need to be

```
$full_name = $form_state['storage']['values'][1]['full_name'];
```

and so on for the other values.